# how to get selected item in an array from another functional component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am working a react - nextjs project.

I want to do When click a destination card, a modal should open which contains the details of that selected destination.

I don't know how to get that selected destination details to this component`<DestinationInfo />`

I tried with

DestinationCard.tsx

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import styles from "./DestinationCard.module.scss";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import DestinationInfo from '../destination-info/DestinationInfo';

const DestinationInCountry = [
  {
    imageSrc: "/images/offers/uk1.jpg",
    postTitle: "Lorem Ipsum",
    postDesc: "Lorem  Sit amet Lorem Ipsum Dolar Sit ametum Dolar Sit amet",
    destination: "London",
    price: "499",
    link: "/",
  },
  {
    imageSrc: "/images/offers/uk2.jpg",
    postTitle: "Lorem Ipsum",
    postDesc: "Lorem  Sit amet Lorem Ipsum Dolar Sit ametum Dolar Sit amet",
    destination: "London",
    price: "249",
    link: "/",
  },
];

const DestinationCard: NextPage = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const openDestinationInfoCard = () =>{
  setOpen(true);
}

  return (
    <>
    {open ? (
      <DestinationInfo  DestinationInCountry= {DestinationInCountry}/>

    ) : ( <div id="destinationCard" className={styles.main_wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.destination_grid}>
        {DestinationInCountry.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className={styles.country_card}
            onClick={() => openDestinationInfoCard()}
            >
              <div className={styles.post_wrapper}>
                <div className={styles.post_title}>{item.postTitle}</div>
                <div className={styles.post_desc}>{item.postDesc}</div>
                <Button>
                  <a> Read more  </a>
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div  className={styles.img_wrapper}>
              <Image
                src={item.imageSrc}
                alt="world pinoy flights - destinations"
                width={400}
                height={400}
              />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

    </div>)}
   </>
  );

}

export default DestinationCard;
```

DestinationInfo.tsx

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from './DestionationInfo.module.scss';

export interface DestinationPlacesProps {
    DestinationInCountry;
}

const DestinationInfo: React.FC<DestinationPlacesProps> = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
        <div className={styles.card_wrapper}>
            <div>
            <Image
                src={props.DestinationInCountry.imageSrc}
                alt="world pinoy flights - destinations"
                width={400}
                height={400}
              />
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default DestinationInfo;
```

**I get this error. Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {"width":400,"height":400}**

How can i get selected item in DestinationInCountry to `DestinationInfo` this component

Comment: Hi, you are passing an array that doesn't contain the imageSrc property. To make this work, you should put {props.DestinationInCountry[0].imageSrc} instead of {props.DestinationInCountry.imageSrc}.

Comment: @JamesLin But It gives same image for all selected destinations. I have different images for each destinations.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array.

```
const [selected, setSlected] = useState('')

//Add an handle for button

const handler = (id) => {
   setSelected(id)
   setOpen(true)
}

<DestinationInfo selected ={selected}/>
```

Comment: please mark it answered if it solves your question]

Answer (score 1):

`DestinationInCountry` is an array. So add index to get `imageSrc`

```
src={props.DestinationInCountry[0].imageSrc}
```

Comment: But It gives same image for all selected destinations. I have different images for each destinations

Comment: using map to render all images like your code below

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

In DestinationCard.tsx

`<DestinationInfo  DestinationInCountry= {DestinationInCountry} selected= {selected}/>`

And

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from './DestionationInfo.module.scss';

export interface DestinationPlacesProps {
    DestinationInCountry;
    selected;
}

const DestinationInfo: React.FC<DestinationPlacesProps> = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
        <div className={styles.card_wrapper}>
            <div>
            <Image
                src={props.DestinationInCountry[props.selected].imageSrc}
                alt="world pinoy flights - destinations"
                width={400}
                height={400}
               
              />
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default DestinationInfo;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.